# Hibernate mapping for cyclic relation ships

Tags: hibernate

I am learning a hibernate and I am developing a very small project for learning purpose. I have a question

I Have two projects
    1. com.common.model
    2. com.amar.model

In first project (com.common.model) has a class called "Person.java" and it has their own "Person.hbm.xml" file.
This person class has a properties like firstname, lastname and etc. This person has many addresses like

```
public class Person {
private String fn;
private String ln;
private Set<Address> addresses;

//getters and setters
}
```

This address class is present in second project (com.amar.model)

```
public class Address {
private String street;
private String city;

private Person person; -- Cause for cyclic dependency. How can I avoid this cyclic dependency and how can I map these properties with hibernate ?

// getters and setters
}
```

This address also has its own "Address.hbm.xml"

There is a dependency on both the classes. I mean one person has multiple addresses and also one address has related to one person only. So If I add an person entry in Address class it will show a cyclic dependency error. If I move this address class in common.model package my problem will solve but in future If I hit this problem how can I overcome this problem.

So how can I avoid this situation and also how can I create a mapping for these two things.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `interface` or `abstract class` into your library and then implement it in your other project.

Your `Address` with have a `Person` which is an `interface` or `abstract class`.

Your `Person` then becomes `PersonImpl` and `implements Person` or `extends Person`.

You then have to tell hibernate about that using [one of the inheritance mapping strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html).

Comment: Thanks @Boris I added my understandings as an Answer. Can you please give a feed back whether my understanding is right or not ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Boris, So first I need to create one more project, this new project can be used by my first two projects. This new project has a new abstract class or interface called Person like this

### In New Project:

```
public abtsract class Person {
//properties

private Set<Address> addresses;

//getters and setters
}
```

### In First Project:

```
public class PersonImpl extends Person {

}
```

### In Second Project:

```
public class Address {
// properties

private Person person;.
}
```

Mapping is done via "Inheritance mapping" this concept. Is it right Boris ?